# How to compute new variable from existing variables in xarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, python-xarray

I have data that consists of measurements of several variables over time for multiple subjects. It's in a 3d xarray.DataArray where the first dimension indexes subjects, the second dimension indexes variables, and the third dimension indexes time. How can I efficiently add a new variable which is a function of the current variables at each time step? For instance, say we have this array

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

x = xr.DataArray(
  np.random.randn(2,3,4), 
  dims=("unit", "variable", "time"), 
  coords={"variable": list("ABC")}
)
```

How can I modify `x` so that it has shape `(2,4,4)`, and the new variable consists of the norm of variables A, B, C at each time step for each subject?

Edit:

I figured out one way to do this:

```
norm = np.sqrt((x*x).sum('variable'))
tfmd = norm.assign_coords(variable='norm').expand_dims('variable', 1)
x = xr.concat((x, tfmd), dim='variable')
```

Is there a more general way to do the first line? And is there a way to shorten the second two lines?

Answer (score 0):

Hei, If you have xarray dataset it is straightforward to add another variable based on the old ones. Terveisin, Markus

```
"""
add new variable based on old ones in xarray
adapted from http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.assign.html
"""

import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "temperature_1": (
            ("lat", "lon"),
            20 * np.random.rand(4).reshape(2, 2),
        ),
        "temperature_2": (("lat", "lon"), 20 * np.random.rand(4).reshape(2, 2)),
    },
    coords={"lat": [10, 20], "lon": [150, 160]},
)
print(ds)
ds = ds.assign(temperature_3=ds["temperature_1"] - ds["temperature_2"])
print(ds)
```